# Is it possible to get the domain name of the script included by a script of a folder with a other domain?

Tags: php, include, dns

An example for my question:

I've a script in the document root (htdocs or what ever) for the domain (as example) "root.co.uk", where I want to generate a link to the "file" domain:

/htdocs/include.file.php

```php
<?php
  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // another.com -> but I like to have "root.co.uk" here :(
?>
```

And now I've a subfolder for the domain (as example) "another.com", which will be loaded via browser:

/htdocs/another.com/index.php -> http://www.another.com

```php
<?php
  include('/htdocs/include.file.php'); // Include file from "root.co.uk"
?>
```

Is there any way to pass the domain name? The only solution, as far as I see, is to define a var like $maindomain = 'root.co.uk'. But thats not the way I like to do it. :(

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What is inside that include file?

Comment: echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

There is no reference from within your PHP files to the web server configuration that specifies what files are in the docroot for the domains being served.  Any `$_SERVER` variables are passed to PHP from the web server for the one request that was made.  Including files does nothing more than include them to execute, which means they will run in the context of the initial request.

Comment: Well Jackie Chan aka "Whoami" eh "Whereami" hmpf ok. I thought also there is no solution for that... :(

Comment: PHP doesn't know or care that the web server has different doc roots for different domains.

Comment: But thanks to you to make that clear.. there should be a pre-defined var à la (__ DOMAIN __) ;)

Comment: PHP doesn't always run in the context of a web server, which is why you won't find any such variable.  As you know, there are variables defined by the server at `$_SERVER`, which is the proper place for them.  As you know, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is generally what you should use.  It contains the value requested by the client in the `Host:` header.  *Usually*, the server will be responding to that header specifically, but not everyone runs their servers in a manner where the `Host:` header is relevant.  Plus, there are still HTTP/1.0 clients that don't use such a header.

Comment: Well I was working on my core script which only exists one time on my server. So for now I call onetime run on first request: Please enter the core host, storing this data and do a request to itself to validate it hrhr ;)